# Fetch specific column in query

Tags: php, pdo

I have this PHP code to fetch the data of a query.

```
$result = $stmt->fetchAll();
```

The result is:

```
array(1) (
  [0] => array(2) (
    [min_date] => (string) 2017-04-27
    [0] => (string) 2017-04-27
  )
)
```

I just need to fetch the min_date value. Help would be appreciated.

Comment: It would be better to change your SQL to just select this value

Comment: @NigelRen it's a stored procedure actually, and I am not that advanced...

Comment: It looks like you're only selecting the one column, but you're using `PDO::FETCH_BOTH` so you get both named and numeric indexes in the rows. Use `PDO::FETCH_ASSOC` to just get the named index.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need to do is add the PDO::FETCH_COLUMN arguement.

```
$min_date = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN, 0)[0];
```

Assuming min_date is the first column in the SQL query table.

EDIT: optimal way:

```
$min_date = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN, 0);
```

Comment: Thank you, but i still get: array(1) ( [0] => (string) 2017-04-27 )

Comment: @Dana will the query always return just one row?

Comment: @Dana I've changed the code so it works to reflect that. with this code `$min_date = '2017-04-27'`

Comment: @Dana no problem! There is a more optimal way, I put it in my answer try using that it makes the code cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the [array_column](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php)() function. It is specifically for things like this.

To get the list of 'min_date' values of all recors:

```
$min_dates = array_column($result, 'min_date');
```

To only get the first one:

```
$min_date = $result[0]['min_date'];
```

But if there are no records returned from the query it will result in an error, so if that can happen do this instead

```
$min_date = isset($result[0]['min_date'])?$result[0]['min_date']:'not_found';
```

to get (string)'not_found' if there are no results or

```
$min_date = isset($result[0]['min_date'])?$result[0]['min_date']:false;
```

to get (bool)false. You get the idea.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I get the result: array(1) (
  [0] => (string) 2017-04-27
)

Comment: @Dana You're welcome. Do you only need the 'min_date' value of the first record, or all of them?

Comment: I just need the first record

Comment: Great, thank you. Now one more last question please. The min date gets returned as a string, and actually in the DB it is a date, can you please help me with returning it as a date?

Comment: There is function called [strtotime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php)(), that will convert that string into a [unix timestamp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time)

Comment: I did this and still get a string... 
$min_date = isset($result[0]['min_date'])? date( "Y-m-d", strtotime( $result[0]['min_date'] ) ) :1;

Comment: The [date](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)() function turns a unix timestamp into string representing that date and time in the format provided. It reverses strtotime(). What do you mean when you say you need it as a 'date'?

Comment: Later on, i try to find a difference between dates, like this:$before = date_diff(getdate(), $min_date); and i cannot get a number because min_date is in string format...

Comment: Have you read the documentation on [php.net](https://php.net)? Please do.
 [date_diff](https://php.net/manual/en/function.date-diff.php) and [datetime.diff](https://php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php)

Comment: I have actually, but it doesn't help me with the issue I have. My problem is that min_date is returned as a string..